# How highlight a div on click in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am having div called `booking-list`,which i am using to display the booking timings.Here on mouse hover the  **background-color** of the **div** is changing as shown in below image.

[image]

Here my issue is,suppose if i click on the first  timings(i,e september1) that div's background as to be changed and that background color should to be constant until i click next timings.something like this below image.I got resources for **list component** but i am unable to apply it for **div**

[image]

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-icon-krdse7?file=app/booking/booking.component.html) link.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ok so this is pretty easy to do with ngClass.
You make a highlight class in your css.
What this will do is it will check if the condition is true and apply the css.

Then you do in the ngFor:

`*ngFor="let item of item; let i = index;" (click)="setRow(i)" [ngClass]="{'highlight': selectedIndex === i}"`

And then in your component:

`public setRow(_index: number) {
  this.selectedIndex = _index;`

In your css you can do something like:

`.highlight{ background-color: green }`

**EDIT**

For multi-selection you can do:

`[ngClass]="{'highlight': selectedIndexs.indexOf(i)}`

`public setRow(_index: number) { 
   if (this.selectedIndexs.indexOf(_index) === -1) {
     this.selectedIndexs.push(_index);
   }
   else {
     let index = this.selectedIndexs.indexOf(_index);
     this.selectedIndexs.splice(index, 1);
   }`

Comment: Or even simpler (and cleaner, IMHO), store the highlighted batch, instead of storing its index: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-icon-sytrlq?file=app/booking/booking.component.html. If you add or remove a batch before the index of the highlighted batch, or if you sort the batches, the selection would change if you store the index. Not if you store the batch itself.

Comment: Your welcome. Also added a basic example how to do this with multi-selection. Only the setRow need some editing for maybe deleting an index if already in the array, if unselect it.

Answer (score 9):

One way is to store the selected item when you click on the div and then use the ngClass directive to apply a class to the selected item:

Markup:

```
<div class="booking-list" 
   *ngFor="let batch of batches" 
   (click)="onClick(batch)" 
   [ngClass]="{ 'selected': batch == selectedItem }">
```

Component:

```
selectedItem = null;

  public batches: IBatch[] = [
    {name: 'Regular', month: 'September 1', time: '10:30 AM - 5:00 PM' , slots: '20/25', color: 'blue'  },
    {name: 'Weekend', month: 'September 10', time: '10:30 AM - 5:00 PM' , slots: '15/25', color: 'red'  },
    {name: 'Weekend', month: 'August 10', time: '12:30 AM - 8:00 PM' , slots: '21/25', color: 'red'  },
  ];

  onClick(item) {
    this.selectedItem = item;
  }
```

css:

```
.selected {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

Here is an updated [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-icon-2bp9cz).

Comment: Thank for your response...:)

Answer (score 1):

I found that [ngClass] was giving me problem with multiple select so here is what I came up with. [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-icon-jgedwq)

- multi selector / multi-select